# Can I get installed applications of phone from user's Windows Live ID in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-sdk, installed-applications

I am developing Windows Phone application in that I want installed applications of phones but I searched a lot on this issue , there is no solution available. So I m trying to get Windows Live ID of windows phone so my question is that from Windows Live ID can I get installed applications in that phone related with that id..?Can anyone help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the use case here? this isn't possible and isn't a standard app requirement so it makes me think there's a better way to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible for a 3rd party developer app to get the list of apps installed on phone. There is no such communication existing in the present versions.

You could use launchers(available in wp8 only) for app to app communication like for opening a file or so. But getting the list of apps installed isn't possible. Atleast not in the present versions.

i.e, Sending data to app  is possible but not receiving the data from one.